# Aspell Spell Checker on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, aspell

I've managed to compile the aspell as a static library for iPhone.
I've the libaspell.a file and included it in my xcode project as a framework.

Does anybody know how to use their c/c++ api for iphone?
Is there any sample or example somewhere on the net?

Thank you for any feedback in advance,
John

Comment: Can you give me details on how you compiled aspell for iOS? Did you also figure out how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you just need to look closer at the documentation. Here is the C API documentation: http://aspell.net/man-html/Through-the-C-API.html#Through-the-C-API

In that doc it says:

> 6.1.3 Examples
>
> Two simple examples are included in
>   the examples directory. The example-c
>   program demonstrates most of the
>   Aspell library functionality and the
>   list-dicts lists the available
>   dictionaries.

It looks fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have another stackoverflow post where I came across some problems while using aspell for iOS. Here is the link to that post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588469/aspell-giving-errors-on-ios-detected-an-attempt-to-call-a-symbol-in-system-lib