# How to check spelling entered in textview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textview, spell-checking

I have one UITextview in which user enter text. after that i take that text as a string and display it in another textview and want the words which are grammatically incorrect.

How to do that?

Comment: Do you just like to provide some way of spelling correction or do you need to know actually?

Comment: Can you outline the behavior of your app a bit more? What are trying to achieve? It does look like work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS system only provide spell checking while the user is inputting text.  If the user choose to type in the wrong word or words, iOS cannot help.  If you want to perform your own spell checking, you will have to include your own spell checking library.

[GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/) is a Free and Open Source spell checker designed to eventually replace Ispell. It can either be used as a **library** or as an independent spell checker.

[Aspell Spell Checker on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745905/aspell-spell-checker-on-iphone) was asked a few years ago here on SO.  I am not sure if they ever got it working.

Comment: It seems that there's no way to use `aspell` as a library on iOS because of the license issue. Check [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-devel/2011-11/msg00001.html). It says **iOS and LGPL are not compatible.**

Comment: [Gnu Lesser General Public License, Section 4, pt. d](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html#section4), say you can statically linked library is allowed if either source code or linkable object files are provided. Also refer to [Which open source licenses are compatible with the Apple's iPhone and its official App Store ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459833/which-open-source-licenses-are-compatible-with-the-apples-iphone-and-its-offici)

Comment: Thanks @BlackFrog, that helps a lot because I am working on using `aspell` as library in iOS. Since you've been paying attention to this issue, do you have any idea how to compile `aspell` for iOS?    Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

Use the UITextChecker class that's been available since ios 3.2: [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use `autocorrectionType` property of `UITextInputTraits` protocol which is implemented by `UITextView`

```
@property(nonatomic) UITextAutocorrectionType autocorrectionType
```

Use it as below

**To disable**

`myTxtview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`;

**To enable**

`myTxtview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes`;

[In Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Correction** option under **Text Input Traits** in `TextField` Attributes using **Interface Builder**. It will take care of Valid English words.

Comment: It will work with the language that the keyboard is set to. Not just English.